# Why won't my array display correctly with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display data using a parent to child relationship with Angular, however I am having issues and am not sure why. I'm trying to display an array of Employee objects, but when I run the webpage on localhost, it displays it as:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

The goal is to inject an Employee service into my EmployeeList componet (parent) and display it using DisplayEmployee (child) component. I can see the data I want being passed through in the console, but not on the webpage. How can I fix this issue, and why does it not recognize the data I'm trying to pass through?

Employee class:

```js
export class Employee {
  private _firstName: string;
  private _lastName: string;
  private _salary: number;
  private _department: string;

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, salary: number, department: string) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._lastName = lastName;
    this._salary = salary;
    this._department = department;
  }

  get firstName(): string {
    return this._firstName;
  }

  get lastName(): string {
    return this._lastName;
  }

  get salary(): number {
    return this._salary;
  }

  get department(): string {
    return this._department;
  }
}
```

Employee Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Employee} from "./employee";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {
  private _employees: Employee[];

  constructor() {
    this._employees = [];
    this.populateEmployees();
  }

  private populateEmployees(): void {
    this._employees.push(new Employee("Kyle", "Ryan", 250_000, "Management"));
    this._employees.push(new Employee("John", "Smith", 50_000, "Human Resources"));
    this._employees.push(new Employee("Nicole", "Berg", 200_000, "Management"));
    this._employees.push(new Employee("Bryan", "Jones", 90_000, "Customer Support"));
    this._employees.push(new Employee("Sarah", "Little", 50_000, "Customer Support"));
  }

  get employees(): Employee[] {
    return this._employees;
  }
}
```

EmployeeList component (parent):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {EmployeeService} from "../services/employee.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  private _allEmployees: any;

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._allEmployees = this.employeeService.employees;
  }

  get allEmployees(): any {
    return this._allEmployees;
  }
}
```

DisplayEmployee component (child):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-employee',
  templateUrl: './display-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-employee.component.css']
})
export class DisplayEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() list: any = "";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

EmployeeList component template:

```html
<app-display-employee [employeeList]=allEmployees></app-display-employee>
```

DisplayEmployee component template:

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let emp of employeeList;">
      <td>{{ emp }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the employee objects using json pipe as following:

```
<td>{{ emp | json}}</td>
```

Comment: this worked, but I'm not trying to display them in JSON format. Any other ideas?

Comment: how do you want to display it? Add an example

Comment: Well seeing as I don't know how to add a picture, I'll try to explain: I'd like to display the data in a table, with each row containing one cell and in each cell display the employee data as plain text

Comment: I recommend that u take a look on matTable Module assuming your’e using angular material - https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview